# jdbc: Get the SQL Type Name from java.sql.Type code

Tags: java, jdbc, jython

I have an array with Field Names and jdbc Type codes.
(Those int codes that you can find in

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.BIT

I use a level 4 Driver.

I can't figure out how to ask the driver for the corresponding SQL (DDL) Type names.
It would be useful in jdbc and in native dialects.

I have
(CustomerId, 1)
(CustomerName, -8)

and I want

(customerId, INT)
(customerId, VARCHAR(200))

Where can I find functions that help me with that?
I am using jdbc in jython via zxJDBC,
so I can use all java and python DB API 2.0 functionality.

Comment: Unless you are still using Java 1.4 I suggest you use the Javadocs for Java 6 (or the version you are using)

Comment: Things changed in Java 8 and later (JDBC 4.2 and later). See the [Answer by YoYo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30444747/642706).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to be using some JDBC metadata methods you have not posted. I believe what you are seeing is the name of the column along with the JDBC [type constant](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html) from which you can derive the column type. Have a look at the [java.sql API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) to read more on how to get more meta data.

Comment: The Types type is actually mentioned in the question.

Comment: "404
We're sorry, the page does not exist or is no longer available." that is why quoting the relevant part with the link makes a btter answer...

Comment: This is not an answer - just a restatement that there is a question.  The correct answer would point the user to where to convert a constant like Types.INTEGER into the string "INTEGER".

Answer (score 48):

## Java 8 and later: `JDBCType` & `SQLType`

With improvements in the API's, as of Java 8 and [JDBC 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html), we have [`JDBCType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/JDBCType.html) and [`SQLType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLType.html), and in the same spirit as some of the other examples can be simply used as follows:

```
String typeName = JDBCType.valueOf(-5).getName();
```

But of course, why using the numeric types to begin with. Make a habit, and switch over from numeric's to the `enum` constants defined in `JDBCType`:

```
String typeName = JDBCType.BIGINT.getName();
```

et voilà!

However, that might not be enough to have something good enough for using in a DDL ... you might need to implement vendor specific translation. As an example, you might need to consider to translate `VARCHAR` to `VARCHAR2` in the case of Oracle.

Comment: This should be the answer. Just to clarify on the answer above regarding Oracle for example - for a column of type VARCHAR2 you will get VARCHAR or for NUMBER you will get NUMERIC or for DATE you will get TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 40):

To specifically answer "Get the SQL Type Name from java.sql.Type code", if you are using a version of java that can do reflection, here is a small utility method that pretty much does the same thing:

```
public Map<Integer, String> getAllJdbcTypeNames() {

    Map<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    for (Field field : Types.class.getFields()) {
        result.put((Integer)field.get(null), field.getName());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Add `import java.lang.reflect.Field;` to your import declarations. Once you have that in place, simply use it as follows:

```
...
Map<Integer, String> jdbcMappings = getAllJdbcTypeNames();

String typeName = jdbcMappings.get(-5); // now that will return BIGINT
...
```

Comment: Very nice.  I adapted this for scala in case anyone needs it: 
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter; 
val sqlTypes = classOf[java.sql.Types].getFields.toList.map(x => (x.get(null).asInstanceOf[Int], x.getName())).toMap

Comment: In 2017 the accepted answer should be YoYo's, but I upvoted this answer as well for creativity.

Answer (score 13):

```
public static String getSqlTypeName(int type) {
    switch (type) {
    case Types.BIT:
        return "BIT";
    case Types.TINYINT:
        return "TINYINT";
    case Types.SMALLINT:
        return "SMALLINT";
    case Types.INTEGER:
        return "INTEGER";
    case Types.BIGINT:
        return "BIGINT";
    case Types.FLOAT:
        return "FLOAT";
    case Types.REAL:
        return "REAL";
    case Types.DOUBLE:
        return "DOUBLE";
    case Types.NUMERIC:
        return "NUMERIC";
    case Types.DECIMAL:
        return "DECIMAL";
    case Types.CHAR:
        return "CHAR";
    case Types.VARCHAR:
        return "VARCHAR";
    case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
        return "LONGVARCHAR";
    case Types.DATE:
        return "DATE";
    case Types.TIME:
        return "TIME";
    case Types.TIMESTAMP:
        return "TIMESTAMP";
    case Types.BINARY:
        return "BINARY";
    case Types.VARBINARY:
        return "VARBINARY";
    case Types.LONGVARBINARY:
        return "LONGVARBINARY";
    case Types.NULL:
        return "NULL";
    case Types.OTHER:
        return "OTHER";
    case Types.JAVA_OBJECT:
        return "JAVA_OBJECT";
    case Types.DISTINCT:
        return "DISTINCT";
    case Types.STRUCT:
        return "STRUCT";
    case Types.ARRAY:
        return "ARRAY";
    case Types.BLOB:
        return "BLOB";
    case Types.CLOB:
        return "CLOB";
    case Types.REF:
        return "REF";
    case Types.DATALINK:
        return "DATALINK";
    case Types.BOOLEAN:
        return "BOOLEAN";
    case Types.ROWID:
        return "ROWID";
    case Types.NCHAR:
        return "NCHAR";
    case Types.NVARCHAR:
        return "NVARCHAR";
    case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
        return "LONGNVARCHAR";
    case Types.NCLOB:
        return "NCLOB";
    case Types.SQLXML:
        return "SQLXML";
    }

    return "?";
}
```

Comment: Outmoded now. This functionality is already coded for you, in the new [`JDBCType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/JDBCType.html) enum that implements [`SQLType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLType.html), as discussed in [sibling Answer by YoYo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30444747/642706).

Comment: BTW as the result might be used in creating a prepared statement, returning "?" might result in a prepared statement parameter being accidentally introduced. Better throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 8):

You need the [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) object of your current `ResultSet`. You can get it with `getMetaData()`. Iterate over the columns and call foreach column the method

1. [`getColumnType(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType-int-)
2. [`getColumnClassName(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnClassName-int-)
3. [`getColumnTypeName(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnTypeName-int-)

of your `ResultSetMetaData`.

`i` represents the column number (starting by 1).

Answer (score 1):

Spring has a handy helper Enum called [`JdbcTypesEnum`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/config/JdbcTypesEnum.html), but it is indeed quite strange, that this is not part of JDBC proper. However, instead of using

```
rs = connection.getMetaData().getColumns();
...
int dataType = rs.getInt("DATA_TYPE");
```

I would use

```
String typeName = rs.getString("TYPE_NAME");
```

when retrieving the column type. For example when inspecting a [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/) table with a special [`VARCHAR_IGNORECASE`](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_ignorecase_type) or `UUID` type:

```
                    dataType   vs. typeName
UUID:               -2=BINARY  vs. "UUID"
VARCHAR_IGNORECASE: 12=VARCHAR vs. "VARCHAR_IGNORECASE"
```

But note, that you cannot cover the type range of the string for all databases, in this case the int would be somewhat more handy (but it is after all not a closed Enum type).

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache DdlUtils Library](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils) has a convenience class for this:
https://db.apache.org/ddlutils/api/org/apache/ddlutils/model/TypeMap.html

```
String typeName = TypeMap.getJdbcTypeName(typeCode)
```

The library helps you also with other DDL needs, but doesn't seem to get much attention lately.

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for SqlType and i found it in this sourcecode
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/sql/Types.java.html